# CGAffineTransformRotate shifts object before performing rotation

Tags: ios

I am trying to animate a transform of a `UIButton` with `CGAffineTransformRotate`, and while it is performing the animation properly, it shifts the button about 15 pixels down and to the left before doing it. Here's the code performing the animated transformation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                 animations:^{
                     self.addCloseButton.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.addCloseButton.transform, degreesToRadians(45));
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

When I reverse the transformation it does the same thing except it shifts it back to its original position before animating (15 pixels up and 15 pixels to the right), and I do that with this code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                 animations:^{
                     self.addCloseButton.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

Why would this shift occur? The button was created using interface builder, and the shift happens immediately even if I set the animation duration higher or add a delay.

Comment: Unless you are applying some kind of `position` or `anchorPoint` adjustment to the underlying layer, I'll bet that your button is simply off-center.

Comment: This happens with any ui element I put in the view though. I tried just throwing a basic UIImage in there and applying the same transition and it jumps down as well. What does it mean for a button to be off-center?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out: turns out having "Use Autolayout" selected on my xib (which adds a bunch of auto constraints) messes things up when trying to use transforms. Turning it off fixed my problem.

Comment: I wish there were a better answer. While turning off constraints may fix the particular problem of the affine transform, it introduces new problems in not correctly laying out in different screen sizes. Isn't there a "best of both worlds" solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is posible to fix this while still using auto layout and storyboards. See my answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19582959